# Error calling standard C library functions from NASM?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, nasm, ld

I'm quite new to assembly programming. I use NASM 2.11.05 on a Windows 7 (64-bit) platform to run some sample code. The problem arises when I try to call standard C functions from my assembly code. This is my assembly source:

```
global  main
        extern  puts

        section .text
main:                                   
        push    message            
        call    puts                    
        ret                             
message:
        db      "Hola, mundo", 0
```

When I compile with NASM, I use this command line: nasm -fwin32 file.asm
which produces file.obj. Now, when I try to link it with ld or gcc, I keep getting errors. Some things I tried:

1. gcc -m32 -nostartfiles file.obj (gives the error that i386:x86-64 architecture of input file is not compatible with i386 output).
2. ld file.obj (gives the error undefined reference to puts).

Can anyone please guide me on how to resolve this?

Comment: On Linux based OS this works for me using your original code without the bits 32 . nasm -felf32 dedduwage_001.s -o dedduwage_001.o  && gcc dedduwage_001.o -o dedduwage_001 -m32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, one line at the top of my ASM file settled it. This is that line.

```
[BITS 32]
```

However, the output file still keeps crashing: anyone who can explain that is welcome!

Comment: It probably crashed because you don't conform to the [CDECL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) calling convention that requires the _caller_ to cleanup the function arguments. Since you pushed 4 bytes of argument data you beed to clean that up after the call with something like `add esp, 4`

Comment: Yep, added this before the return:

pop ebp

and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just compile in a different way, like:

Create an object of your `.asm` file with:

1. GCC: `nasm -f elf file.asm`
   or
2. LD: `ld -m elf_i386 file.o -o file`

Link object file created with `gcc -m32 -o file file.o`

Run with `./file`

Comment: He is targeting native Windows executables.